# How to wait for animation end in ui-router $stateChangeStart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-animate, angular-ui-router

I use AngularJs in my project and ui-router within it.

I need gently fade out current view before navigate user to another one when he clicks on the link.

I've written directive for that and here is the link function for it:

```
link: function($scope, element) {

            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
                function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

                var $element = $('#fw');

                $element.animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, 4000, function () {

                });

        }
```

But of course transition executes immediately and doesn't wait for animation ends.

I neither found solution to make jQuery animation sync nor suspend ui-router transition and then continue it in the animation callback.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

the ui-router has built in support for animations, is there some reason you're using a custom directive?

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-animate-ui-view-with-ng-animate

There is a plunkr link on that page you can experiment with too-

Comment: Yes, I need to have more control over animation which I can't achieve with build in one.

Comment: could you setup a "dummy" animation using the built in animation, for the same amount of time, and then run what you want to do concurrently